# Modifying SharePoint List Using ASMX WebServices

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010, asmx, sharepoint-2013

I am writing a custom piece of code that dynamically creates modified document libraries. I've attempted to create a document library template, which succeeds in the UI but cannot be found via-webservices.

So to get to the point - I am attempting to:
 1. Set "Allow Management Of Content Types" on the list.
 2. Add a new Content Type (Already Created) to the list.
 3. Set the new content type as the default content type.
 4. Remove the "Document" content type from the list.

So far I have succeeded in being able to "Apply" the custom content type but the others are evading my grasp. The methods I have attempted are through the Lists.asmx service and the method described here: **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/websvclists.lists.updatelist.aspx**

I tried setting the Flags property and a few other potential candidates with no success and ***no error messages*** complaining about what I was trying to attempt.

One limitation is that I do NOT have access to the sharepoint dll where this is living.

Once completed - this would be a plugin living in another non-sharepoint system. The only option to include the SharePoint client dll's would be to perform an ILMerge.

EDIT: 
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj193051.aspx (SharePoint 2013 Web Services)** 
**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814(v=office.16).aspx (SharePoint 2010 Web Services)**
and yes - technically the ASMX services sound like they're on their way out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/jj164060.aspx

Edit: Tags are relevant to the question.

Comment: You're going to need to show code, describe what is happening, what you expect to be happening, and what, if any, error messages you are receiving if you want an answer. Also, limit your tags to what the post is *actually* about, it isn't both Sharepoint 2010 and 2013. Do the asmx services even still exist in 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SharePoint Client Object Model. This is a library that wraps calls to webservices that allows among other things to batch commands.

The operations you mention are all available.

here is a link to an article that explains Client Object Model:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-2010-Client-Object-Model-Introduction

The article focus on ListItems but you can also interact with list properties, even web properties if you want.

Please note that you don't need to run Client Object Model from your sharepoint server. Note the "Client" part in the name.

Comment: This is what I've found on the web as well - several implementations utilize this method but the documentation for the asmx services is vague at best in regards to what I'm attempting. If the licensing allows me to redistribute the dll's via ILMerge then I may use this.